# How do I detect the screen brightness range on android?

Tags: android, brightness, screen-brightness

I'm using the following code to set the screen brightness, which works fine on most phones:

```
    protected fun setBrightness(value: Float) {
        //Set the system brightness using the brightness variable value
        Settings.System.putInt(contentResolver, Settings.System
            .SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, (value * 255).toInt())
        //Get the current window attributes
        val layoutpars = window.getAttributes()
        //Set the brightness of this window
        layoutpars.screenBrightness = value
        //Apply attribute changes to this window
        window.setAttributes(layoutpars)
    }
```

When I pass a value of 1, meaning maximum value, this gets converted to 255 which is said to be the greatest value to set the screen brightness. However, on a Xiaomi Mi8 setting the value to 255 won't set the brightness to the full range, as seen in this screenshot:

[image]

After printing some debug values and experimenting, it looks like on the Xiaomi Mi8 the maximum brightness value is actually 1024 (or at least, multiplying 1 by that value sets the full brightness bar).

It seems that different android devices might have different brightness scales. Is there some API to get the maximum value in brightness so I don't need to hardcode different constants?

Comment: Did you find any usable solution for this? Which solution did you implement in the end?

Comment: I added a text box to let users specify a max value manually.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I did as well (but with a spinner with predefined values). Do you have any experience about which values exist? As far as I know, 255, 1023 and 3999 (based on the answer) do exist..

Comment: No idea, but on some Xiaomi phones inserting a higher value threw an exception, so I let users put any value and catch errors.

Comment: ok, thanks for your feedback

Comment: Xiaomi Note 5 Pro has a maximum value of 4095 ((2^12)-1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is specific for some Xiaomi devices. For example Xiaomi Redmi Note 7 has 0-4000 range.

Official documentation defines SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS range as 0-255. So, I think there are no API to get the maximum value in brightness.

On some (not all) devices there is a file "/sys/class/leds/lcd-backlight/max_brightness" that can contain max value.

Comment: Is the file "/sys/class/leds/lcd-backlight/max_brightness" in every device, or is it just for Xiaomi? I cannot find it in my device. Do I have to be root to access it?

Comment: **_some_** devices. It's undocumented, so it is not reliable. It is not Xiaomi specific.

Comment: At least affects OnePlus and Xiaomi. With different range! Aswin answer seems to do the trick though.

Comment: I'm experiencing similar situation. On Huawei, Xiaomi devices on Android 10, brightness works incorrectly.

Answer (score 7):

Use this method to get max value for brightness

```
public int getMaxBrightness(Context context, int defaultValue){

    PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    if(powerManager != null) {
        Field[] fields = powerManager.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field: fields) {

            //https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/os/PowerManager.java

            if(field.getName().equals("BRIGHTNESS_ON")) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                try {
                    return (int) field.get(powerManager);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    return defaultValue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return defaultValue;
}
```

I have tested this on a couple of devices (mostly android 9, 10 devices, including some xiaomi devices, which usually set brightness higher than the usual 255), and looks like this is working.

> Google does not promote accessing hidden fields/methods using reflection. Any android update could potentially break this solution.

**Another possible solution** would be accessing `getMaximumScreenBrightnessSetting()` method in PowerManager class using reflection. But I haven't tested it and therefore cannot confirm the results.

**NB** : If you are using this value to set brightness percentage, keep this in mind : From android 9 onwards, brightness is set [logarithmically](https://www.stkent.com/2018/11/12/more-on-android-pies-brightness-control-changes.html#:%7E:text=The%20brightness%20control%20change%20we,screen%20is%20dark%20versus%20bright.). So setting brightness percentage might not look like the percentage shown in brightness slider (Lower percentages might look higher than set value on brightness slider), but the physical brightness will be set right.

Comment: Thanks for that finding, it works just fine on POCO F2 Pro! Max is 2047

Answer (score 1):

Instead of you set 255 as the max value. I prefer to use this way to set brightness to max. Just passing 1F to the screenBrightness.

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams layout = getWindow().getAttributes();
layout.screenBrightness = 1F;
getWindow().setAttributes(layout);
```

It's working fine on different android devices.

Comment: Doesn't work on OnePlus (need to set it to 4F) and doesn't work on POCO F2 Pro either where it needs to be set to 8F.

Answer (score 1):

I've also tried to get the brightness (logarithmic variant as of Android P, API 28). This is what I've done (see below code):

- Reverse engineered the publicly available APIs from Google (https://cs.android.com/),
- Used reflection to get the minimum and maximum brightness values,
- Took the required mathematical methods from MathUtils and

Simply call getCurrentBrightness to retrieve the percentag brightness value. Unfortunately, even by using that setup, I couldn't exactly determine the same brightness value as shown in the Android display settings...

I've also tried to use brightnessIntToFloat (PowerManager / BrightnessSynchronizer; code also included below), but without success.

Do you have any idea what could still be wrong?

```
public class BrightnessUtils {
        public static double getCurrentBrightness(Context mContext) {
            float screenBrightness = 0;
            try {
                screenBrightness = Settings.System.getFloat(mContext.getContentResolver(), "screen_brightness");
                //float test = brightnessIntToFloat(screenBrightness);
            } catch (Exception e){
                Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
            }
    
            return getPercentage((double) (screenBrightness != 0 ? convertLinearToGammaFloat(screenBrightness, getMinimumScreenBrightnessSetting(mContext), getMaximumScreenBrightnessSetting(mContext)) : 0), 0, 65535);
        }
    
        public static float norm(float start, float stop, float value) {
            return (value - start) / (stop - start);
        }
    
        public static float sqrt(float a) {
            return (float) Math.sqrt(a);
        }
    
        public static float log(float a) {
            return (float) Math.log(a);
        }
    
        public static float lerp(int start, int stop, float amount) {
            return lerp((float) start, (float) stop, amount);
        }
    
        public static float lerp(float start, float stop, float amount) {
            return start + (stop - start) * amount;
        }
    
        public static float constrainedMap(
                float rangeMin, float rangeMax, float valueMin, float valueMax, float value) {
            return lerp(rangeMin, rangeMax, lerpInvSat(valueMin, valueMax, value));
        }
    
        public static float lerpInvSat(float a, float b, float value) {
            return saturate(lerpInv(a, b, value));
        }
    
        public static float lerpInv(float a, float b, float value) {
            return a != b ? ((value - a) / (b - a)) : 0.0f;
        }
    
        public static float saturate(float value) {
            return constrain(value, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        }
    
        public static float constrain(float amount, float low, float high) {
            return amount < low ? low : (amount > high ? high : amount);
        }
    
        public static float brightnessIntToFloat(int brightnessInt) {
            final float minFloat = 0.0f;
            final float maxFloat = 1.0f;
            final float minInt = 1;
            final float maxInt = 255;
            return constrainedMap(minFloat, maxFloat, minInt, maxInt, brightnessInt);
        }
    
        public static int convertLinearToGammaFloat(float val, float min, float max) {
            final int GAMMA_SPACE_MIN = 0;
            final int GAMMA_SPACE_MAX = 65535;
    
            // Hybrid Log Gamma constant values
            final float R = 0.5f;
            final float A = 0.17883277f;
            final float B = 0.28466892f;
            final float C = 0.55991073f;
            // For some reason, HLG normalizes to the range [0, 12] rather than [0, 1]
            final float normalizedVal = norm(min, max, val) * 12.0f;
            final float ret;
            if (normalizedVal <= 1f) {
                ret = sqrt(normalizedVal) * R;
            } else {
                ret = A * log(normalizedVal - B) + C;
            }
    
            return Math.round(lerp(GAMMA_SPACE_MIN, GAMMA_SPACE_MAX, ret));
        }
    
        private static double getPercentage(double d, int i, int i2) {
            if (d > ((double) i2)) {
                return 1.0d;
            }
            double d2 = (double) i;
            if (d < d2) {
                return 0.0d;
            }
            return (d - d2) / ((double) (i2 - i));
        }
    
        public static float getMinimumScreenBrightnessSetting (Context context) {
            final android.content.res.Resources res = android.content.res.Resources.getSystem();
            int id = res.getIdentifier("config_screenBrightnessSettingMinimum", "integer", "android");
            if (id != 0) {
                try {
                    return res.getInteger(id);
                }
                catch (android.content.res.Resources.NotFoundException e) {
                    // ignore
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }
    
        public static float getMaximumScreenBrightnessSetting (Context context) {
            final android.content.res.Resources res = android.content.res.Resources.getSystem();
            final int id = res.getIdentifier("config_screenBrightnessSettingMaximum", "integer", "android");
            if (id != 0) {
                try {
                    return res.getInteger(id);
                }
                catch (android.content.res.Resources.NotFoundException e) {
                    // ignore
                }
            }
            return 255;
        }
    }
```